# Is there any penalty or effect for not making it to bed by 3AM in Portia?

Tags: my-time-at-portia

In the game *My Time at Portia*, the workable/playable day ends around 3AM. Unlike similar games with this mechanic like *Stardew Valley*, there doesn't appear to be any monetary or item cost if you fail to make it back to your bed by 3AM in *Portia*.

However, I can't tell if there is any other effect to passing out at 3AM that I might be missing. The game also doesn't seem to mention this in detail on any of the loading screens I've seen thus far.

Answer (score 5):

A [long thread on Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/666140/discussions/0/1727575977587715755/) about this occurrence highly implies there's no penalty to staying up late, by noting how there's no penalty.